# Polynomial for product over a set

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials, induction, roots, roots-of-unity

> **Conjecture:**
>   If $A$ is a nonempty, finite set with size $|A|=n$, and 
>   $$P_A(x)=\prod_{a\in A}(x-a),$$
>   then $P_A(x)$ can be expanded as
>   $$P_A(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^{n-k}x^k\sum_{{U\subseteq A}\atop{|U|=n-k}}\prod_{u\in U}u.\tag{1}$$

I have conjectured this based on algebraic evidence. That is, I expanded out the cases $n=1,...,4$ both manually and through $(1)$, and in each case the conjecture held. The problem is, I'm having difficulty proving this result. I'm fairly certain that a proof would involve induction, but I'm not very good at that, and have so far failed.

I was initially interested in this formula because I recognized that $(1)$ would imply that 
$$k\ne0,n\iff \sum_{{U\subseteq S_n}\atop{|U|=k}}\prod_{u\in U}u=0\tag{2}$$
for 
$$S_n=\left\{\exp\frac{2\pi ik}{n}:k=0,1,...,n-1\right\}.$$
It may seem un-intuitive at first, but $(2)$ is true because 
$$P_{S_n}(x)=x^n-1,$$
(as $S_n$ is the set of roots of $x^n-1$) so each term of the expansion must vanish except for the cases $k=0,n$.

After seeing this, I was naturally curious about a proof of $(1)$. Could I have some help or hints? Thanks.

Comment: The relation between product of linear factors and the polynomial written as a sum of powers goes by the name of [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you have discovered the [elementary symmetric polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) and their relationship with the coefficients of a given polynomial (see Section 3, Properties, at the link above).

Comment: Thank you for that nice link, do you have a proof to go along with it?

Comment: Just search the web or check university-level algebra books—it's a fundamental and well-known enough fact that you'll find proofs everywhere. (There are two references at that link, for that matter.)

Comment: With all due respect, if it's so fundamental and well-known, then you shouldn't have any trouble typing it up right now, should you? Again, I do not mean to be rude, but I feel that when someone asks an (at least decent) question on MSE, they deserve a complete, thorough answer. I asked for a proof, not a link to a Wikipedia page which just restates my conjecture in a slightly different way.

Comment: You may not mean to be rude, but not being willing to search on your own and expecting Greg Martin to lay it all out for you *is* rather rude.

Comment: Fundamental and well known does not necessarily mean easy to write up.

Comment: @TheCount I'd like to apologize for being rude. I'm really sun-burnt, and I think its making me cranky. In regards to my lack of research, what would you recommend that I look up in order to find the proof I'm looking for? In other words, what is the name of the theorem I have 'discovered'?